# Looking for divisibility by 29 and a general proof( if any)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, divisibility, combinatorial-proofs

Is there any elegant way to prove that <sup>28</sup>C<sub>14</sub> -1 is divisible by 29? Also, is this kind of a result a theorem or a generalisation? If so please do help...

note i do mean 28 choose 14

Comment: Is this symbol supposed to mean "$28$ choose 14?"

Comment: Yes  it does mean 28 choose 14...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714352/finding-divisibility-of-a

Comment: Ah that's quite a nice generalisation,thanks!

Comment: The LaTex for $\binom {28}{14}$ (which means $^{28}C_{14}$) is \binom {28}{14}

Comment: Ah thanks will help in posing question in future 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you mean $\binom{28}{14}-1$?

Note that
$$14!\binom{28}{14}=28\times27\times26\times\cdots\times 15
\equiv(-1)(-2)(-3)\cdots(-14)=14!\pmod{29}.$$
Therefore $\binom{28}{14}\equiv1\pmod{29}$.